# Show a Google Calendar in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, google-workspace, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a hosted Exchange account for my work email (not Office 365) and some new clients/partners I am working with are all-in for Google. I've setup a Google account with my hosted Exchange email address and they have shared their Google calendars with me, so how do I get those calendars to show up in Outlook? When I'm inside my Google account I see a way to get an iCal or HTML address, but when I click the iCal one the URL has "public" in it and I just get a failed message when I try to pull that up.

I'm trying to avoid having to login to Google to look at their calendars every time before sending invites, but also can't switch from my hosted Exchange account to Google apps (nor would I want to).

Any ideas?

Comment: On a Mac, the Calendar app can work with Exchange and Gmail. Not so much in Outlook. You can subscribe to read-only Internet calendar in Outlook 2013. Outlook's iCAL support is not fully compliant so recurring events error out. You can also use your iPhone/iPad as that also can handle Exchange and Gmail calendars perfectly. Microsoft really blows when it comes to Office programs and supporting open standards. When they do support, it is half assed and not fully compliant. You know how look Outlook took to support IMAP and even decently? It took them over 10 years!

Comment: I kind of figured that'd be the case. Hopefully Satya will fix this...eventually!

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/See-your-Google-Calendar-in-Outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126 -- you can add  Google calendar outlook when you are the original owner. You can't add to outlook a shared calendar owned by someone else... Unless the owner gives you the private iCal url of their Google calendar account.

Comment: Nice find! I will have to see if they will give me the URL for their calendar. My guess is they would. Thanks!

Comment: In outlook you can't edit but adding it to your google calendar you should have full rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st - A correction to the misunderstanding Microsoft Outlook's handling of IMAP.  MS Outlook has been able to easily handle IMAP and any other standard as well as the non-standard email account types with little effort now for over 10 years.
The recent sync issues with Google Calendar and Contacts has been caused by Google during their roadmap to push G-Suite services as a competing option to Microsoft Office.  If you are willing to pay for the G-Suite services, Google makes available their Google-Outlook sync tool.  Which is essentially their tool that fixes the breaks they created.  But this tool is NOT free, for it REQUIRES a G-Suite subscription. 
There are other 3rd party tools currently available to have their own way to navigate through the crap Google configuration changes that make it so so clear, Google is doing everything it can to be a monopoly and does little more than lip service to maintaining national and international standards.